# Disconnection issues in Selenium tests

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on fixing issues with Selenium tests designed to test submitting a review in a number of categories on a website, and I'm running into a problem with the connection dropping while a request is being performed. The errors seem to be nondeterministic- they don't always occur, and happen before the set timeout for a given action. I'm running the Selenium hub on a CentOS virtual machine (on my local machine), which seems to make network issues unlikely, since the webserver is running locally on my machine as well. I'm running into two main exceptions: "Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.", and CLIENT_GONE. I've included a sample of each of them below. If I run the tests 50 times, they might fail on anywhere from 10-30% of the time, while the rest of the time they run without an issue. Is there something I'm missing relating to the virtualbox connection, or how I could be using Selenium? Thanks in advance.

Stack trace for the UnreachableBrowserException:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.5.0-49-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_60'
Driver info: driver.version: CoreDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:569)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getPageSource(RemoteWebDriver.java:414)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.Augmenter$CompoundHandler.intercept(Augmenter.java:280)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$58bad765.getPageSource(<generated>)
    at com.foo.selenium.CoreDriver.captureScreenAndSource(CoreDriver.java:537)
    at com.foo.selenium.CoreDriver.captureScreenAndSource(CoreDriver.java:513)
    at com.foo.selenium.CoreDriver.captureScreenAndSource(CoreDriver.java:497)
    at com.foo.selenium.CoreDriver.waitForElementToAppearInElementByLocator(CoreDriver.java:378)
    at com.foo.selenium.CoreDriver.waitForElementToAppearInElementByLocator(CoreDriver.java:343)
    at com.foo.bar.reviewtest.ResponseTest.verifyResponse(ResponseTest.java:121)
    at com.foo.bar.reviewtest.ResponseTest.runATest(ResponseTest.java:48)
    at com.foo.bar.reviewtest.UserTestBase.testDriver(UserTestBase.java:129)
Caused by: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 1207803; received: 0
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:204)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.close(ContentLengthInputStream.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity.streamClosed(BasicManagedEntity.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.checkClose(EofSensorInputStream.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.close(EofSensorInputStream.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.consume(EntityUtils.java:85)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor$EntityWithEncoding.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:412)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:300)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:527)
    ... 39 more
... Removed 27 stack frames
 org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.5.0-49-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_60'
Driver info: driver.version: CoreDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:569)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getPageSource(RemoteWebDriver.java:414)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.Augmenter$CompoundHandler.intercept(Augmenter.java:280)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$58bad765.getPageSource(<generated>)
    at com.foo.selenium.CoreDriver.captureScreenAndSource(CoreDriver.java:537)
    at com.foo.selenium.CoreDriver.captureScreenAndSource(CoreDriver.java:513)
    at com.foo.selenium.CoreDriver.captureScreenAndSource(CoreDriver.java:497)
    at com.foo.selenium.CoreDriver.waitForElementToAppearInElementByLocator(CoreDriver.java:378)
    at com.foo.selenium.CoreDriver.waitForElementToAppearInElementByLocator(CoreDriver.java:343)
    at com.foo.bar.reviewtest.ResponseTest.verifyResponse(ResponseTest.java:121)
    at com.foo.bar.reviewtest.ResponseTest.runATest(ResponseTest.java:48)
    at com.foo.bar.reviewtest.UserTestBase.testDriver(UserTestBase.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1338)
    at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1307)
Caused by: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 1207803; received: 0
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:204)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.close(ContentLengthInputStream.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity.streamClosed(BasicManagedEntity.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.checkClose(EofSensorInputStream.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.close(EofSensorInputStream.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.consume(EntityUtils.java:85)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor$EntityWithEncoding.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:412)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:300)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:527)
    ... 39 more
```

And the second error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Session [fa85a873-517b-4054-8690-cccc02e17f41] was terminated due to CLIENT_GONE
Command duration or timeout: 2.56 seconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.5.0-49-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_60'
Session ID: fa85a873-517b-4054-8690-cccc02e17f41
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, chrome.chromedriverVersion=26.0.1383.0, acceptSslCerts=false, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=false, webdriver.remote.sessionid=fa85a873-517b-4054-8690-cccc02e17f41, version=26.0.1410.63, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:307)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:299)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.Augmenter$CompoundHandler.intercept(Augmenter.java:280)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$29d6fa2e.findElement(<generated>)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:523)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$0(ExpectedConditions.java:521)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$10.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:289)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$10.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:208)
    at com.tools.selenium.CoreDriver.waitForElementToBeInvisible(CoreDriver.java:300)
    at com.tools.selenium.CoreDriver.waitForElementToBeInvisible(CoreDriver.java:288)
    at com.foo.bar.reviewtest.ResponseTest.loginOnVisit(ResponseTest.java:55)
    at com.foo.bar.reviewtest.ResponseTest.runATest(ResponseTest.java:44)
    at com.foo.bar.reviewtest.UserTestBase.testDriver(UserTestBase.java:129)
Caused by: org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Session [fa85a873-517b-4054-8690-cccc02e17f41] was terminated due to CLIENT_GONE
    at org.openqa.grid.internal.ActiveTestSessions.getExistingSession(ActiveTestSessions.java:104)
    at org.openqa.grid.internal.Registry.getExistingSession(Registry.java:423)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.getSession(RequestHandler.java:234)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process(RequestHandler.java:116)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process(DriverServlet.java:84)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:565)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:479)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1031)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:965)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:452)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:47)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:894)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:948)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:857)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:66)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:254)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty7.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
... Removed 30 stack frames
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you get anywhere with this issue?  I'm seeing the second issue (CLIENT_GONE) very regularly.

We run a suite of Selenium tests (about 200) overnight regularly, and for the past two nights have had hundreds of instances of this.

About 96% of the errors are from
get_PageSource

The vast majority are also taking over 25 minutes to produce this error, so it looks like it might be a timeout issue.

Comment: This answer should be deleted and instead added as a comment to the original question.

Comment: This is not an answer.